# Any() on String

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I don't understand what is going on here under the hood.
I having a simple string:

```
 var aux = "Hello";
```

and if I run:

```
aux.Any();
```

it returns **True** . The **Any()** executed is in the System.Core dll:

[image]

Is there a cast under the hood where the string gets converted into an Enumerable of chars and **Any()** verifies if the list is empty or...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: basically: yes.

Comment: _Is there a cast under the hood where the string gets converted into an Enumerable of chars_ A string **is** an Enumerable of chars: it implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: See msdn IEnumerable example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: In short, it's a rather strange way of testing is a string is the empty string or has any characters in it.

Comment: @Alejandro does `str.Any(char.IsUpper)` strike you as strange? If not, why would `str.Any()`?

Comment: Even though a string is an `IEnumerable<char>`, there is a better way to check if a string is empty - simply check it's length, or call `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or even `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `String` starts with

```
public sealed class String : IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, ICloneable, IComparable, IComparable<string?>, IConvertible, IEquatable<string>
{ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` implements interfaces `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<Char>`. And

> You can write LINQ queries in C# for ... any collection of objects that supports IEnumerable or the generic IEnumerable interface.

(from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/))

It works like this because LINQ is just [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for these interfaces.